# Weird sequence of characters temporarily when opening file

Tags: startup

I know the title isn't all too descriptive but I don't have a better way to describe it. Whenever I open a file with `vim` (but interestingly not `nvim`), a bizarre sequence of characters shows under the cursor until I take my first action in the file, at which point it disappears, revealing the content that would ordinarily be there. Here are a couple pictures that show the issue better:
[image: vim when first opening file]

[image: after first action]

Comment: Which version of vim are you using? Have you tried a more recent one? (there used to be a similar bug a few hundreds  (thousand?) patches ago)

Comment: Also if you have a newer version, posting your `vimrc` in your question might be useful.